# Programming mobile devices

Tags: mobile

I love desktop and web programming, but I would like to be able to program some sort of small device I can then carry with me. Most mobile phones are quite hard to create programs for as they want you to buy the things they offer instead.

- What mobile-phone/gameboy size devices would be suitable for my goal?

Answer (score 1):

An Android phone?

SDK is free.  You can release things how you like ... it could be for free from the market place ... you could sell it through the market place.  You could do the same through your website ... its up to you.

Comment: It's **not free** to publish applications in Market: Before you can publish software on the Android Market, you must do three things:
..."Pay a registration fee ($25.00) with your credit card (using Google Checkout)"... (http://market.android.com/publish/signup)

Comment: I said you could release FOR free FROM the market place.  Nothing stopping you releasing totally freely on the web though.

Answer (score 0):

Classic Palm PDA.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com/products?q=programmable+calculator

Since your goal is so vague, all of these qualify.  You might want to consider refining or expanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write applications for **Android** for free (SDK, emulator, IDE etc is available for download without paying a fee). That is, any Android enabled device would do.

(There is a fee if you want to publish your application in Market though, but it's easy to install programs without going through Market.)

Answer (score 0):

Some I would try:

[GP2X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GP2X)

[Openmoko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openmoko)

[Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29)-based devices

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with writing in C#, C++ or VB.NET, writing Windows Mobile applications would be very easy for you. You can Visual Studio with Windows Mobile SDK to develop the application.

Android is another very good choice of writing applications with a huge and growing market.

Symbian OS is compatible with most of the Nokia Phones.

If you can write a J2ME application, i suppose it can run in almost any phone (Not sure about the iPhone)

However this all depends on the phone you have and the programming languages you are competent in :)

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously look at an Android phone.

The HTC range in particular work really well as phones at least as well as an iPhone.

Google has put together a really well thought out framework and SDK which well put together and well documented, the only downside seems to be that you need to install the bloatware that is eclipse.

Most of the HTC phones support UMTS, EDGE and Wi-Fi so you have lots of connectivity options. You usually get GPS, motion sensors and "Haptic" included. All of which makes for a million possible apps.

Also you can juts buy the phone and insert your SIM. No need to marry AT&T or divorce your current provider.

Answer (score 0):

Any of today's smartphones would meet the goals of your question. As you can see everyone has their 'pet' platform that they want to promote to you.

1. examine your skills - what
   do you know.
2. define your
   goals - what you want to do
3. consider your carrier limitations
   (if any) - are you in a contract you
   cant break? Is a smart-phone right
   for you?
4. consider who you
   are developing for - yourself?
   limited audience? the public?